# How to get rid of localdb in SSDT?

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I am unable to use my database project after migrating from VS2010 to 2012.

All scripts for the database objects in the project are connected to the automatically-created localdb database. I am not interested in localdb since the database is large and I maintain it in a full-blown instance of SQL Server 2008 R2.

I tried all possible settings in Tools-Options-Database Tools-Data Connections-SQL Server Instance name to no avail. After re-loading the projects, it always restores the same connection to localdb.

My problem is that I need to refer from one database to another. I do it with synonyms:
CREATE SYNONYM [pcg].[practice] FOR  [PcgDb].[Portal].[practice];
This script is automatically linked to localdb and the PcgDb on localdb has no tables. Hence I an getting an unresolved reference error 71501.

I tried also all combinations in Add Database Reference, even added my instance of SQL Server to the localdb linked servers, still the same error.

Comment: Did you try changing the target connection string on the "Debug" tab of the project properties?

Comment: Andrew is correct here - the answer is that F5 deployment is based on the target connection string in the Debug tab. You must change that on a per-project basis. Separate to that, the right-click "Publish" option for the project allows you to publish to other databases than the debug target (which is only intended for use in a quick "code->debug->validate" loop, not full deployments). Generally we'd encourage you to develop against a test instance, whether on a 2008 server or localdb, then use full publish to your regular server once you've good confidence your changes make sense.

Answer (score 0):

When you first create the SSDT project, the first step should be importing the target database; at that time you can specify you live instance of SQL Server. You shouldn't need to "get rid of" the local DB, it should just be ignored at that point. Perhaps this is happening since you migrated an existing 2010 project? In that case I would suggest you just create a new Project and do the import from the live server.